# How to make specific architecture in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I want to create a firebase with the following structure:

```
fireBaseName:
  user1:
    name: name,
    email: email
  user2:
    name: name,
    email: email
  user3:
    name: name,
    email:email
```

but I can't seem to add to append data to the firebase without firebase creating a custom key for it. For example, if I want to append user1 to start out with, the data that gets created is

```
firebaseName:
  funkyKey: user1
```

How would I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your code, because for example are you trying to use restful or sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yang Li's solution will work.

Here's another one (requires the Firebase JavaScript SDK):

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/');
var name = 'name';
var email = 'email';

ref.set({ 
  fireBaseName: 
    user1:
      name: name,
      email: email
    user2:
      name: name,
      email: email
    user3:
      name: name,
      email:email
  }
});
```

Or:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(index) {
    ref.child('user'+index).set({
        name: name,
        email: email
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using restful services, You can achieve this like

```
function postUser(user, name, email){
  $http.put('https://<yourfirebase>.firebaseio.com/fireBaseName/' +user + '.json', {name: name, email: email}).success(function(){
    console.log('done');
  })
}

postUser('waz', 'jacob', 'jacob@jacob.com');
postUser('waz1', 'jacob1', 'jacob2@jacob.com');
postUser('waz2', 'jacob2', 'jacob2@jacob.com');
```